# How to get each URLs of the website using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am currently automating the website in which the URL is constantly changing (SSO like website).. In that we are passing parameters in querystring.. I want to capture each of the URLs the website goes through to reach to the specific page. How can I achieve that using Selenium Webdriver..

I tried driver.getCurrentUrl() on regular intervals, but it is not reliable..

Is there any other work-around for this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Mashkurm what do you mean by `but it is not reliable`? Maybe you're just using `.getCurrentUrl()` in an unreliable way. **:)** Did you wrap your `.getCurrentUrl()` statements in `ExplicitWait`s? Anyways, if you're trying to capture a massive amount of `URL`s, then Selenium is not the way to go. You should maybe try using **JSoup**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the following:

```
    driver.get("http://www.telegraph.co.uk/");
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    List<String> externalUrls = new ArrayList();
    List<String> internalUrls = new ArrayList();

    System.out.println(links.size());

    for (int i = 1; i <= links.size(); i = i + 1) {
            String url = links.get(i).getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println("Name:"+links.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println("url"+url);
            System.out.println("----");
            if (url.startsWith("http://www.telegraph.co.uk/")) {
                if(!internalUrls.contains(url))
                    internalUrls.add(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            } else {
                if(!externalUrls.contains(url))
                    externalUrls.add(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            }
        }
```

If you want to gather all the links for your website, then I would do something like:

```
public class GetAllLinksFromThePage {

    static List<String> externalUrls = new ArrayList();
    static List<String> internalUrls = new ArrayList();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyChromeDriver myChromeDriver = new MyChromeDriver();
        WebDriver driver = myChromeDriver.initChromeDriver();

        checkForLinks(driver, "http://www.telegraph.co.uk/");

        System.out.println("finish");

    }

    public static void checkForLinks(WebDriver driver, String page) {
        driver.get(page);
        System.out.println("PAGE->" + page);
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        for (WebElement we : links) {
            String url = we.getAttribute("href");
            if (url.startsWith("http://www.telegraph.co.uk/")) { //mymainpage
                if (!internalUrls.contains(url)) {
                    internalUrls.add(we.getAttribute("href"));
                    System.out.println(we.getText() + " has added to internalUrls");
                    checkForLinks(driver, url);
                }

            } else if (!externalUrls.contains(url)) {
                externalUrls.add(we.getAttribute("href"));
                System.out.println(we.getText() + " has added to externalUrls");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Hope that helped!